# Cannot access Ubuntu Unity 14.04 (Crouton)

Tags: 14.04, unity, chromebook, crouton

I installed Unity on my HP 14" Chromebook and it worked just fine. I updated to Unity 14.04 inside of Unity, but after the 'restart to finish updates', I have been unable to start unity since.

This is what happens after `sudo startunity`

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startunity
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Wed Feb 22 23:33:28 PST 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2539520 verity payload=PARTUUID=eb3db7f2-8aa6-df4b-aab6-13b7ff0a095a/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=eb3db7f2-8aa6-df4b-aab6-13b7ff0a095a/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2539520 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=93a1adc452180e54e4c0731f523e30bd5cf56b5d salt=7e7970866f6931bd04e4ccbf00e2e938cf45cfe7aca7f894ee68c3bc34b738b7" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=eb3db7f2-8aa6-df4b-aab6-13b7ff0a095a add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Sun Feb 26 17:46:22 2017
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
crouton: version 1-20170223114115~master:71d1c2f5
release: precise
architecture: amd64
xmethod: xorg
targets: unity
host: version 9000.91.0 (Official Build) stable-channel kip 
kernel: Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Wed Feb 22 23:33:28 PST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
freon: yes
Running exit commands...
/usr/bin/xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down Hangup
(EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

This is really driving me crazy! Once I input `sudo startunity` into the shell, the screen goes dark, as it would when it transitions over to Unity, but then goes back to my ChromeOS screen.

Comment: `release: precise` suggests nothing was upgraded.

Comment: how do I upgrade whatever it is that needs to be upgraded?

Comment: Better to do the other way around: Edit your question and post what you did to "update to Unity 14.04". It should be noted that specifics about installing Ubuntu in Chromebooks is off-topic here. Ubuntu itself once installed is on topic though.